# jQuery Datepicker can't set date

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have problem with set date in datepicker.
I get date from other input field and try to use in new Date() but it's not working. This field work fine I can get date from input in other space of project but here it doesnt work:

```
$(function () {
    $('#empBirthDate').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        language: 'pl'
    }).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
    var birth = $('#birthID' + empEvidenceNumber).text();
    var day = parseInt(birth.substr(0, 2));
    var month = parseInt(birth.substr(3, 5));
    var year = parseInt(birth.substr(6, 10));
    $('#empBirthDate').datepicker().datepicker("setDate",new Date(year,month,day));
});
```

but I do this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#empBirthDate').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        language: 'pl'
    }).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
    $('#empBirthDate').datepicker().datepicker("setDate",new Date(2000,11,22));
});
```

Then everything works so I think problem is with my variable but I exactly don't know what? I tried simple variable like

```
var birth = '22-11-2000';
```

use this as string argument in Date and this works too.

I checked many times and my variable:

```
var birth = $('#birthID' + empEvidenceNumber).text();
```

works, I can display it where I want but not in datepicker. Always I get current date checked in datepicker.
Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What's it giving you as the date? Can you show more of the html.

try:

```
$('#empBirthDate').datepicker().datepicker("setDate",new Date(year,month-1,day));
```

Comment: I tried and still nothing, I know months start indexing from 0 to 11. If I use #empBirthDate to set value in other input field it is always well formated date like "14-01-2018"

Comment: What is it setting as the date? What is it showing and what do you want it to say?

Answer (score 0):

your substr() not use in collect way. see below.

```html
    var day = parseInt(birth.substr(0, 2));
    var month = parseInt(birth.substr(3, 2));
    var year = parseInt(birth.substr(6, 4));
```

I don't know if this help or not ??